# chrome extension addListener and sendMessage synchronous usage

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I need to wait for information from the DOM via the content script and use that in the listener in the background script.

I'd like to run this code synchronously but running into async issues, the listener calls `suggest` before the getFilename function returns. <strike>How do I run this synchronously?</strike>

*background.js*

```
function getFilename(AAA, fn) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {data: AAA.text }, function(response) {
                appendfn = response.data || "SRTING";
                fn = fn.replace(..., '-' + appendfn);
                return fn; // this is correct
            });
        });
}


chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(downloadItem, suggest) {
    if (downloadItem.url.substr(...) == "DOMAIN") {
        var appendfn = "";
        var fn = downloadItem.filename;

        fn = getFilename(downloadItem, fn); // why doesn't this block? is it because suggest is used as a callback?

        console.log(fn); // undefined  
        suggest({filename : fn})
    }
});
```

*content.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
   var elm = document.querySelectorAll(... msg.data);
   sendResponse({data: elm.text});
});
```

The correct question to ask is not: how do I run this synchronously, rather **how can I get it to work asynchronously**? When framed like that the answer is simple.

Comment: You can't run it synchronously. There's no such option in chrome API with callbacks (except a few exceptions like the blocking webRequest). Rework the code properly to use the value inside the callback. Also, `return fn` inside sendMessage callback does nothing useful.

Comment: I'm a JS newbie so still wrapping my head around this. I'd appreciate if you link to docs and preferably examples of proper usage you are mentioning.

Comment: Well, I think googling for async javascript tutorial is too easy to link it. Or you can wait for someone else to post a ready-to-use answer.

Comment: I've read the tutorials but I dont see how to re-structure this as they are both asynchronous. `suggest` doesnt accept call backs and calling `addListener` as a callback on `getFilename`/`sendMessage` doesnt make sense.

Comment: Basically you'll need to nest all callbacks inside onDetermining -> tabs.query -> sendMessage -> then call suggest()

Comment: Hmm.. don't see how that will work as `downloadItem` is needed from `onListener` to send with `sendMessage`

Comment: So? Variables from outer nesting functions are available in the inner nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was over complicating things -- all I had to do was `return true` at the end of the `addListener` to enable async call of `suggest`.

If you have an elegant Javascript-y solution, please share :)